# How to handle Japanese on Windows and Linux using SDL_ttf and C++?

Tags: c++, windows, sdl2, c, linux

In SDL_ttf, there are a few functions provided that handles non-ASCII string literals, such as:

- `TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid`
- `TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid`

and etc. I'll be using only the two functions as part of my question.

Currently, I'm fussing over whether to stick to using `TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid` or `TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid`, mainly because I wanted my program to be able to work flawlessly on both Windows and Linux. (No plans for Mac, because of lack of hardware).

I know for a fact, on Windows, they used UTF-16 for handling wide characters. It's pretty straightforward to use Japanese for SDL, by using `TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid` and the use the following code, that I'm currently using, to convert from `wchar_t` string literals to `Uint16*` type that the SDL_ttf uses:

```
static inline Uint16* Convert(wchar_t LString[]) {
    return reinterpret_cast<Uint16*>(&(LString[0]));
}
```

Thus, I can easily do:

```
SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid(font, Convert(L"い"), this->color);
```

But, given that any string literals, `L""` is a `wchar_t[]` type, it makes things more complicated for me if I were to port this over to Linux. The only way I know of compiling code for Linux is to use GCC, and GCC clearly defines `wchar_t` to be of 32 bits long.

Of course, I can just straight up use the UTF8 versions:

- `TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid`

And just use string literals, such as `u8"あ"`, or `u8"いいえ"`, and they will all work in most cases. The problem here is, when I store these string literals and then inspect the variables in the debugger, I would not get the values I wanted. The stored data would suffer from integer overflow, like so:

[image]

Where at the top, I used `u8"あ"` and for bottom, I used `L"あ"`. You can see how the value is no longer preserved when using UTF8 strings, but the value is preserved when using `wchar_t` type strings.

Thus, I really can't use `TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid` in SDL_ttf to help me with Japanese encoding.

**May I ask what is the best way to go about this? And how I should correctly handle Japanese on both Windows and Linux platforms?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

In C++, the compiler knows what a `u8""` string literal is, and will convert that string literal appropriately to an UTF-8 compatible string.

And since it's UTF-8, it means each character is separated into 8-bits long bytes. With this in mind, you can just point a `char*` at the string literal, and it will work as if it's an ASCII `char*` string.

The Visual Studio's Immediate Window only displays ASCII characters, and will convert some parts of UTF-8 compatible characters into multiple bytes, then display each byte as if they are ASCII characters. This will create an allusion that the values are getting integer overflowed. I was merely tricked by this until now.

Thus, the best way to render text is to use the provided UTF-8 methods:

`SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid(font, u8"い", this->color);`

And then it should work from there. No need to do any conversion whatsoever.

Comment: Given the PITA that text encoding are, especially when tools mislead you; and the fact that you walked through every detail clearly, I have to disagree with the first sentence. ***downvote***